# Reuse MustacheFactory and Mustache compilation

Tags: java, mustache

Here my code:

```java
MustacheFactory mustacheFactory = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
Mustache mustache = mustacheFactory.compile(requestID);

StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
mustache.execute(outWriter, parameters).flush();
String request = outWriter.toString();
```

Is any of those classes thread safe?

I mean, I'm performing the code inside a spring boot service. Each time an HTTP request is reached, I'm creating a `MustacheFactory` and I'm compiling template.

Could I cache them and reuse them?

Any ideas?